# How to make an AutoCompleteField in Eclipse just like Refactoring Dialog?

Tags: autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

This question is related to Eclipse plug-in development.

I want to code an SWT Text field (or Combo) just like the "Return type" field in the "Change Method Signature" refactoring dialog page. I would like to have the same auto complete behavior as in this field.

I know I could use AutoCompleteField and TextContentAdapter, but I have no idea how to set the proposals array with all the classes in the project classpath. What about those image decorations to the left of the class name?

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a ContentProposals example only or to you want to know how to get all the class names in the classPath? With the first thing I can help you. Hope this code helps, if you have questions then just ask.

```
package com.porsche.dps.core;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.eclipse.jface.bindings.keys.KeyStroke;
import org.eclipse.jface.bindings.keys.ParseException;
import org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.ContentProposal;
import org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.ContentProposalAdapter;
import org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.SimpleContentProposalProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.fieldassist.TextContentAdapter;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProviderListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class ContentProposalsTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Display display = new Display();
      Shell shell = new Shell(display);
      shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

      Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);

      String[] proposals = new String[] {"abc", "bcd", "cde", "abc2", "bcd2", "cde2"};
      String autoActivationCharacters = "";
      SimpleContentProposalProvider simpleContentProposalProvider = new     SimpleContentProposalProvider(proposals);

      for (int i = 0; i < proposals.length; i++) {

         if (proposals[i].length() == 0)
            continue;

         char c = proposals[i].charAt(0);

         if (autoActivationCharacters.indexOf(c) == -1) {
            autoActivationCharacters += c;
         }
      }

      KeyStroke keyStroke = null;
      simpleContentProposalProvider.setFiltering(true);
      try {
         keyStroke = KeyStroke.getInstance("Ctrl+Space");
      } catch (ParseException e) {
         Logger.getLogger("").error("KeyStroke Parse Exception");
      }
      ContentProposalAdapter proposalAdapter = new ContentProposalAdapter(text, new TextContentAdapter(),
     simpleContentProposalProvider, keyStroke, autoActivationCharacters.toCharArray());

          proposalAdapter.setProposalAcceptanceStyle(ContentProposalAdapter.PROPOSAL_REPLACE);
      proposalAdapter.setLabelProvider(new ILabelProvider() {

         @Override
         public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {}

         @Override
         public boolean isLabelProperty(Object element, String property) {
            return false;
         }

         @Override
         public void dispose() {}

         @Override
         public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {}

         @Override
         public String getText(Object element) {
            return ((ContentProposal)element).getLabel();
         }

         @Override
         public Image getImage(Object element) {
            return <insert image>;
         }
      });
      shell.open();
      while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
         if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
         }
      }
      display.dispose();
   }
}
```